# Snowflake handling duplicates in merge operation

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a problem handling duplicates from source table. This seems to be like issue with source where I wanted to handle them while loading into target as I don't have options to check in source system.

Sample Source table data - TAB_SOURCE

```
ID  CD          CT      NOI         QTY VER PID DESC
1   19700101    200050  10          1   1.0 123 
1   19700101    200050     10                   Got Error
2   20210101    190050  09          2   1.0 345 
2   20210101    190050     09                   Success
5   20211001    150151  02          1   1.0 987 Success
```

Required Target table entry - TAB_TARGET

```
ID  CD          CT      NOI         QTY VER PID DESC
1   19700101    200050  10          1   1.0 123 Got Error
2   20210101    190050  09          2   1.0 345 Success
5   20211001    150151  02          1   1.0 987 Success
```

I'm using below merge statement for loading data from source to target. Consider Source data has been loaded into landing schema in the same database where target table lies.

```
Merge into target.TAB_TARGET as tgt using
( select * from landing.TAB_SOURCE) src
on tgt.ID = src.ID and tgt.CD = src.CD and tgt.CT = src.CT and tgt.NOI = trim(src.NOI)
when matched then update set
tgt.ID = trim(src.ID),
tgt.CD = trim(src.CD),
tgt.CT = trim(src.CT),
tgt.NOI = trim(src.NOI),
tgt.QTY = trim(src.QTY),
tgt.VER = trim(src.VER),
tgt.PID = trim(src.PID),
tgt.DESC = trim(src.DESC)
when not matched then insert
(ID,CD,CT,NOI,QTY,VER,PID,DESC)
values
(trim(ID),trim(CD),trim(CT),trim(NOI),trim(QTY),trim(VER),trim(PID),trim(DESC));
```

The issue here is DESC column value is coming as separate entry with NOI(One of the key on Merge) column having preceding whitespaces with the values for few records and I want those to be considered as a single record by populating DESC along with other columns as shown in target table entry.

Can someone help me to achieve the source data to be loaded into target as per the sample shown in target.

Comment: Hi - you just need to re-write you SELECT statement so that it returns the data that you want

Comment: Hi @NickW can you please share few sample on the same. I don't have any idea on how to get the desired result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work - plus you only need to use TRIM in one place rather than in both the match and not matched statements:

```
SELECT TRIM(ID) AS ID, TRIM(CD) AS CD, TRIM(CT) AS CT, TRIM(NOI) AS NOI, 
MAX(TRIM(QTY)) AS QTY, MAX(TRIM(VER)) AS VER, MAX(TRIM(PID)) AS PID, MAX(TRIM(DESC)) AS DESC
FROM landing.TAB_SOURCE
GROUP BY TRIM(ID), TRIM(CD), TRIM(CT), TRIM(NOI)
```